# Change the behaviour of Filter components in a <List> View

Tags: admin-on-rest

I have a requirement whereby the front-end client is supposed to wait for the user to click on a "Search" button before fetching the query back to the back-end server for the filtered results. I have followed the tutorials and the `5. The <List> View` section, but there is no specified documentation for such proclivity.

```
const CategoriesFilter = (props) => (
  <Filter {...props}>
    <TextInput label="Search Category" source="hierarchy_name" alwaysOn />
    <SelectInput label="Filter by Category Type" source="type" choices={[
      {id: 'all', name: 'All'},
      {id: 'interest', name: 'Interest'},
      {id: 'place', name: 'Place'}
    ]} alwaysOn />

  </Filter>
);

export const CategoriesList = (props) => (
  <List {...props} title="Categories List" filters={<CategoriesFilter />}>
    <Datagrid>
        …
    </Datagrid>
  </List>
);
```

At the moment, it sends query back to the server as I am typing, which is what I do not want. Appreciate any kind souls for my assistance.